# Make your own custom oneboxes for Chat!

Tags: script, chat, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

Oneboxing is when you post a link to a supported site on SE Chat and it automatically shows extra information. An example is when you post a link to a question in Chat and it converts to the title, start of the body and author.

However, the list of [supported sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57287/260841) is short, and there are feature requests such as [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243259/260841) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106425/260841) (from 2011) for certain sites to be added, but they've gotten nowhere so far.

**So, I've made a userscript that lets *you* (or others) to create 'plugins' for Chat Oneboxing.**

#### Usage

**Users**:

1. Install the userscript.
2. Copy and paste a plugin that someone has made just above the `--------------------------------` in the middle of the script. That's it!

**Developers**: It's really simple:

1. Install the userscript (so you can make and test your plugin)
2. Make a HTML string containing all the data you need (ie. your onebox). You would probably use a 3rd-party API to get any information you need for the onebox.

**There are examples and notes about creating plugins in the answers below! :)**

#### Download

You can install it from the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/shu8/SE-Chat-Custom-Oneboxes/raw/master/custom-oneboxes.user.js).

You can also view the source at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/shu8/SE-Chat-Custom-Oneboxes/blob/master/custom-oneboxes.user.js).

If you make a plugin, please post it as an answer below, as I have done! :)

Comment: Can you do your magic to allow CORS?

Comment: @Yummy what do you mean??

Comment: I'm just kidding, I wanted to know if it allows CORS and bypasses the Same Origin Policy

Comment: @YummyUnicornRainbowTails oh lol - nope :( It's expected that you would probably use an API to get all your information! :)

Comment: Haven't tested it yet, but a doubt: all interested users must have the userscript installed for this to work, or is it "universal"? IMHO, this is not clear in your description... Oh, yeah, do you know if I upvote all your 3 answers, serial vote script will get me? ;)

Comment: @brasofilo yes, this userscript must be installed -- I'll make that clear in a sec. And no problem -- just upvote the answer you like the most :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Notes

1. All you need to do to add your own oneboxed site is add a function to the customSites object (ie. add a 'plugin' :)
2. The function must be named as the URL you want to onebox (eg. SoundCloud -> `soundcloud.com` as the function name)
3. The function must have the parameters `link` and `$obj`, in that  order! `link` = the matched link; `$obj` = the message as a jQuery element
4. If you want additional CSS (which is likely), you have 3 options (in order of preference):

   - Use GM_addStyle (requires adding `// @grant GM_addStyle` to the usersript metadata block at the top)
   - Add a CSS file by adding it to the head: $('head').append(''); - The URL could be a github file
   - Use inline `style=""` attributes for each element
5. If you need to, you can make an extra function if things start getting complex :)

In its most basic form, a 'plugin' can look like:

```
customSites['customsite.com'] = function(link, $obj) { //all sites must have a function like this, with those parameters. Change the 'customsite.com' to whatever your desired URL is
    var template = "<div class='ob-container'>A onebox!</div>" // A HTML String (ie. your oneboxed div)
    $obj.html(template);
}
```

But you probably want to use some sort of API to actually get the information!

---

### An example -- oneboxing SoundCloud links

```
customSites['soundcloud.com'] = function(link, $obj) { //Example: Oneboxing SoundCloud links
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/shu8/SEChat-soundcloudOneboxer/master/style.css">'); //Some custom CSS as an external stylesheet
    var client_id = 'f557cccd917d8ff72fb731f9b6b3aee5'; //My client ID for the SoundCloud APi
    $.get("http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url="+link+"&client_id="+client_id, function(d) {  //Using the SoundCloud API
        //Get the desired information:
        var user_avatar_url = d.user.avatar_url;
        var username = d.user.username;
        var artwork_url = d.artwork_url;
        var title = d.title;
        var playback_count = d.playback_count;
        var genre = d.genre;
        var permalink = d.permalink_url;
        var tags = d.tag_list; 
        var desc = d.description;
        var track_no = d.id;

        //Make a string containing all the tags with enclosed spans
        var tagsList = '';
        if(tags.length) {
            tags=tags.match(/(?:[^\s"]+|"[^"]*")+/g); //http://stackoverflow.com/a/16261693/3541881
            for (var i=0; i<tags.length; i++) {
                tagsList += "<span class='tag'>"+tags[i].replace(/"/g, '')+"</span>";
            }
        }

        //Make a HTML string, with the contents of the desired onebox div:
        var template = "<div class='sc-onebox'> \
                                       <div class='info'>"+username+"</div> \
                                       <div class='title'><a href='"+permalink+"'>"+title+"</a></div> \
                                       <div class='main'> \
                                           <img src='"+(artwork_url ? artwork_url : user_avatar_url)+"' /> \
                                           <div class='tags'>"+(tagsList ? tagsList : "No tags")+"</div> \
                                           <br> \
                                           <div class='desc'>&nbsp;"+(desc ? desc : "There is no description for this item :(")+"</div> \
                                           <div class='player'><iframe width='100%' height='100' scrolling='no' frameborder='no' src='https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/"+track_no+"'></iframe></div> \
                                       </div> \
                                   </div>";
        $obj.html(template); //add the oneboxed div. Done!
    });
};
```

Results in:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Oneboxing arXiv links

```
customSites['arxiv.org'] = function(link, $obj) {
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/shu8/SE-Chat-Custom-Oneboxes/master/arxiv.css">');
    var id = link.split('/')[4];
    if (id.indexOf('pdf') > -1) {
        id = id.replace('.pdf', '');
    }
    $.get("http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query="+id, function(d) {
        var $xml = $(d);
        console.log($xml);
        var title = $xml.find('entry title').text();
        var author = $xml.find('entry author').text();
        var summary = $xml.find('entry summary').text();
        var url = $xml.find('entry link[type="text/html"]').attr('href');
        
        var template = "<div class='arxiv-container'> \
                            <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h65A.jpg' /> \
                            <div class='title'><a href='"+url+"'>"+title+"</a></div> \
                            <div class='author'>"+author+"</div> \
                            <div class='desc'>"+summary+"</div> \
                        </div>";
        $obj.html(template);
    }); 
};
```

Comment: @E.P. sorry, my bad. It's been fixed in this answer now :)

Comment: Cool =). Any chances we can tempt you into making a DOI oneboxer?

Comment: @E.P. I'd be more than happy to -- few questions tho 1) who's 'we' :P 2) what's DOI? :/ and 3) do you have any thoughts on what the onebox could look like?

Comment: DOIs are Digital Object Identifiers and they're the main ID of research papers, so you can link to, say, http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0953-4075/48/15/151001, and it is the persistent identifier of the paper. It would be nice to get much the same information as in the arXiv onebox - title, authors, nicely-formatted bibliographic citation, abstract, and link to the paper. I'm not sure it's trivial, though.

Comment: @E.P. ahh I remember looking into this once before (lol and forgot what they were :P) and the problem was that there isn't one single standard for every paper in the way that they give the DOI so it would have been incredibly unreliable :(. If there are specific sites for which you want the DOI for, that should be easier because each site has their own standard...

Comment: Yeah, I imagine that's probably what'll happen. =|.

Comment: @E.P. I know it's probably really annoying, but yeah, if there are a few main sites, I could look into that for you :)

Comment: Nah, it's too big of an ask. I'll look into it when I have time ;-).

Answer (score 1):

### Oneboxing Spotify Links

```
customSites['play.spotify.com'] = function(link, $obj) {
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/shu8/SE-Chat-Custom-Oneboxes/master/spotify.css">');
    if(link.indexOf('album') > -1) {
        var album_id = link.split('/')[4];
        $.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/"+album_id, function(d) {
            var url = d.external_urls.spotify;
            var image = d.images[0].url;
            var artist = d.artists[0].name;         
            var name = d.name;
            var type = d.type;
            
            var template = "<div class='spotify-container'> \
                                <img src='"+image+"'> \
                                <div class='info'>"+type+"</div> \
                                <div class='title'><a href='"+url+"'>"+name+"</a></div> \
                                <div class='artist'>"+artist+"</div> \
                            </div>";
            $obj.html(template);
        });
    } else if (link.indexOf('artist') > -1) {
        var artist_id = link.split('/')[4];
        $.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/"+artist_id, function(d) {
            var url = d.external_urls.spotify;
            var image = d.images[0].url;
            var name = d.name;
            var type = d.type;
            
            var template = "<div class='spotify-container'> \
                                <img src='"+image+"'> \
                                <div class='info'>"+type+"</div> \
                                <div class='title'><a href='"+url+"'>"+name+"</a></div> \
                            </div>";
            
            $obj.html(template);
        });     
    } else if (link.indexOf('track') > -1) {
        var track_id = link.split('/')[4];
        $.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/"+track_id, function(d) {
            var url = d.external_urls.spotify;
            var name = d.name;
            var type = d.type;
            var artist = d.artists[0].name;
            
            var template = "<div class='spotify-container'> \
                                <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQJQ0.png'> \
                                <div class='info'>"+type+"</div> \
                                <div class='title'><a href='"+url+"'>"+name+"</a></div> \
                                <div class='artist'>"+artist+"</div> \
                            </div>";
            
            $obj.html(template);
        });         
    }   
};
```

Answer (score 1):

### Oneboxing links to Stack Exchange user profiles (the main site)

```
customSites['stackexchange.com'] = function(link, $obj) {
    if(link.indexOf('/users/') > -1) {
        var user_id = link.split('/')[4];
        $.getJSON("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/"+user_id+"/associated", function(json) {
            var oldestSiteUserId = json.items[0].user_id;
            var oldestSite = json.items[0].site_url.split('/')[2].split('.')[0];
            var oldestSiteRealName = json.items[0].site_name;
            
            $.getJSON("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/"+oldestSiteUserId+"?order=desc&sort=reputation&site="+oldestSite+"&filter=!9YdnSA07B", function(json2) {
                var display_name = json2.items[0].display_name,
                    location = json2.items[0].location,
                    image = json2.items[0].profile_image,
                    about = json2.items[0].about_me;
                var template = '<div class="onebox ob-user">\
                    <div class="user-gravatar64">\
                        <a href="http://stackexchange.com/users/'+user_id+'">\
                            <img height="64" width="64" alt="" src="'+image+'">\
                        </a>\
                    </div>\
                    <div>\
                        <img width="20" height="20" src="http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/apple-touch-icon.png" >\
                        <a class="ob-user-username" style="color: #4E82C2;" href="http://stackexchange.com/users/'+user_id+'">'+display_name+'</a>, '+location+'\
                    </div>\
                    <div style="overflow: auto;    height: 50px;">\
                        '+about+'\
                    </div>\
                 </div>';
                 
                 $obj.html(template);                
            });
        });        
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Oneboxing Steam Store links

```
customSites['store.steampowered.com'] = function(link, $obj) { // http://store.steampowered.com/app/377840/
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/shu8/SE-Chat-Custom-Oneboxes/a043cfaae462d918f94558e188749089ef9d97cb/steam.css">');
    var id = link.split('/')[4];
    $.get("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22"+encodeURIComponent('http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids='+id)+"%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=", function(d) {
        data = d.query.results['_'+id.slice(1)].data;  
        tags = '';
        $.each(data.categories, function() { tags += '<span class="ob-post-tag">' + $(this)[0].description + '</span>'; })
        var template = "<div class='steam-container'> \
                            <img src='"+data.header_image+"' /> \
                            <div class='title'><a href='"+link+"'>"+data.name+"</a></div> \
                            <div class='tags'>" + tags + "</div> \
                            <div class='desc'>"+data.short_description+"</div> \
                        </div>";
        $obj.html(template);
    }); 
};
```

Comment: Steam  has updated their API to include the `short_description`, which is the text that appears beneath the `header_image` when viewing the store page for the game.  This script should probably do the same (replacing `about_the_game`).  CSS also looks to need updating as the header image takes up more vertical space than the text at some resolutions.

Comment: @MBraedley Thanks for the CSS fixes you did on github! :) I'll look into updating the short_description ASAP! :) I'm really sorry I took so long to respond! I've been really busy :(

Comment: Just submitted an edit.  Wasn't going to do it behind your back or anything.

Comment: @MBraedley Thanks! That was easier than I thought it would be :P thanks for all the changes you've made again :))

Answer (score 0):

#### Oneboxing OEIS entries

```
customSites['oeis.org'] = function(link, $obj) {
    var id = link.split('/')[3];
    if(id) {
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/shu8/SE-Chat-Custom-Oneboxes/master/oeis.css">');
        $.get("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" + encodeURIComponent('http://oeis.org/' + id) + "%22&callback=", function(d) {
            var $document = $(d);
            var $table = $document.find('form').parent().next();
            var number = $table.find('table:eq(1) td:eq(0)').text().trim();
            var desc = $table.find('table:eq(1) td:eq(2)').text().trim();
            var sequence = $table.find('table:eq(2)').text().trim().replace(/ *\([^)]*\)/, ''); //http://stackoverflow.com/a/4292483/3541881
            var template = "<div class='oeis-container'>\
                              <span class='id'>[OEIS]: <a href='"+link+"'>"+number+"</a></span>\
                              <span>"+desc+"</span>\
                              <span class='sequence'>"+sequence.replace(/ *\([^)]*\)/, '')+"</span>\
                            </div>";
            $obj.html(template);
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

### Oneboxing etymonline definitions

```
customSites['etymonline.com'] = function(link, $obj) {
    var term = link.split('?')[1].split('term=')[1];
    if(term) {
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/shu8/SE-Chat-Custom-Oneboxes/master/etymonline.css">');
        $.get("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" + encodeURIComponent('http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=' + term) + "%22&callback=", function(d) {
            var termToDisplay = $(d).find('#dictionary dt:eq(0)').text(),
                definition = $(d).find('#dictionary dd:eq(0)').text();

            var template = "<div class='etymonline-container'>\
                              <span class='term'>[etymonline]: <a href='"+link+"'>" + termToDisplay + "</a></span><br>\
                              <span>" + definition + "</span>\
                            </div>";

            $obj.html(template);
        });
    }
};
```